# "Where" command (Windows) not working when there are space characters in paths?

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, namespaces

If I do:

```
>where notepad*.*
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

but when I try:

```
where Amb*.* /r "i:\Descargas Automatizadas\"
ERROR: El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos.
```

sorry, but my Windows is in spanish, so the translation would be something like:

```
ERROR: Filename, path or syntax in volume label are wrong.
```

My workaround is:

```
mklink /d AmberMichaels "i:\Descargas Automatizadas\"
>where Amb*.* /r AmberMichaels
h:\Temporal\Pruebas\AmberMichaels\AmbMicMeg_Amber_Michaels_-_18_and_Lost_in_Miami_sc2_Frank_Fortuna.wmv
h:\Temporal\Pruebas\AmberMichaels\AmbMicMeg_Amber_Michaels_-_ForceFantasies.com_clip1.wmv
```

It works, but for scripting matters I think this should be a problem, at least when searching in directories with spaces (that is: if the space character is the problem here, what I don't know for sure). Furthermore, in Windows 7 creating a link (*mklink* command) requieres elevation (admin).
Am I wrong, maybe there is some sort of update to *where* command that solves this issue?
If not: what could be the best way to deal with this issue when scripting?

Answer (score 1):

```
where Amb*.* /r "i:\Descargas Automatizadas"
```

Remove the tailing backslash

Comment: Thanks, @MCND, but I would like to know why some simple `dir "i:\Descargas Automatizadas\"` work as well as `dir "i:\Descargas Automatizadas"`. This is: how could we define the rule for tailing backslashes?